# SMS not being sent in telegram and no log registered

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

Trying to send SMS to telegram group whenever we receive new SMS. I tried to run below code but when new SMS arrives, there is no activity.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = "1234:ABC";
    private static final String TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID = "-5678";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    if (pdus != null) {
                        for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                            String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                            sendToTelegram(messageBody);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void sendToTelegram(String message) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN + "/sendMessage");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("chat_id", TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID);
                jsonParam.put("text", message);

                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(jsonParam.toString());
                wr.flush();

                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("TelegramResponse", "Response Code: " + responseCode);

                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TelegramError", "Error sending message to Telegram: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I sent a test message to the number where the app is installed but when new SMS arrives, there is no activity. Not sending anything in telegram and o Log detected in logcat

Comment: Only the main SMS app will receive all SMS on Android. Malware was capturing SMS too often so Google eliminated that risk. Other apps can only get specially formatted SMS verification messages.

Comment: Then how Truecaller is reading the messages? or the even google message? @Robert

Comment: Note that there are two APIS: one for receiving incoming messages (this one is restricted to the default SMS app) and one for reading SMS in the SMS database (not sure which security restrictions apply for this api).